# checking API value within an If or Switch statement

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin

I'm working on a project where we are using an api to communicate as a link between between back-end and front-end.

I'm new to using API and have only previously used connection strings with built in queries or stored procedures within the C# programming language. Currently I'm working with Xamarin.Forms and I want to know if anyone has a solution to this.

We have different statutes for one value and I want to change the label color depending on status so something like this.

```
public ExtendedLabel MyApiValue { get; private set; }

            var MyApiValue = new ExtendedLabel()
if(MyApiValue = "The Status of the API");
        {
            FontFamily = "Poppins-Regular.ttf",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("Green"),
            Text = " Verified ",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

    else;
        {
            FontFamily = "Poppins-Regular.ttf",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("Red"),
            Text = " Verified ",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
```

Bear in mind that his code has syntax errors, I'm not after a correction of the code. Just a path of how to solve this. I want to access a value in my API and use it to format a label differently depending on the status of the API for my UI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make your states as an enum

```
public enum SomeState {
    ok, error, unkown
}
```

This way you can easily use them in a `switch` and you don't have to deal with some magic constants but you have actual meaningful names.

```
SomeState x = ...;

switch(x) {
    case SomeState.ok: ... break;
    case SomeState.error:  ... break;
    case SomeState.unkwown: ... break;
}
```